# Delphi XE 7 Read process memory

Tags: delphi

My current code:

```
var
 something : integer;
    try
       something := byte(Pointer(integer(Pointer($0059724C)^)+76)^);
    except

    end;
```

How to check if address $0059724C contain valid data? Now it works but sometimes exception is raised. My goal is to remove try except. Thanks for replies.

UPDATE:
looks like this doesnt generate AV

```
 if byte(Pointer($0059724C)^) = 0 then numerZaznaczonegoGracza := fOstatnioZaznaczonyGracz
else
begin
numerZaznaczonegoGracza := byte(Pointer(integer(Pointer($0059724C)^) + 76)^);
fOstatnioZaznaczonyGracz := numerZaznaczonegoGracza
end;
```

Comment: May I ask, where the "magical" value $0059724C + 76 comes from? Sounds very much like you are trying to solve a completely different problem than what you tell us here.

Comment: The assignment can be re-written as `something := PByte(PInteger($0059724C)^+76)^;`. If you are actually trying to add 76 to $0059724C itself, not to the integer that $0059724C points at, then it becomes even simplier: `something := PByte($0059724C+76)^;`

Comment: Please define "valid" for your purposes.

Comment: @JensG $0059724C contains some address. I want to read it and later add 76 to get new address, finally read byte which i need.

David Heffernan hmm i guess diffrent from 00 00 00 00. 

Remy Lebeau thanks, i will try diffrent things later.

Comment: @mca64 Just read the value, and trap the av

Comment: @mca64: Sure, but that doesn't answer the question, where the numbers are come from and why it can't be $ABCDEF01 and 4711, for example. I have some more numbers, if you need one.

Comment: Its depressing that i dont see obvious things. Thanks @ David Heffernan !!

Comment: @ JensG doest it matter from where it comes? If you have more number then please give. Much appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altough the Windows API offers a function for this purpose, [`IsBadReadPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366713(v=vs.85).aspx) is by no means a failsafe way to determine whether or not a piece of memory is accessible. But it can at least act as an indicator.

From the MSDN:

> **This function is obsolete and should not be used.** Despite its name, it does not guarantee that the pointer is valid or that the memory pointed to is safe to use. [...]
>
> Threads in a process are expected to cooperate in such a way that one
>   will not free memory that the other needs. Use of this function does
>   not negate the need to do this. If this is not done, the application
>   may fail in an unpredictable manner.
>
> Dereferencing potentially invalid pointers can disable stack expansion
>   in other threads. A thread exhausting its stack, when stack expansion
>   has been disabled, results in the immediate termination of the parent
>   process, with no pop-up error window or diagnostic information.
>
> If the calling process has read access to some, but not all, of the
>   bytes in the specified memory range, the return value is nonzero.
>
> In a preemptive multitasking environment, it is possible for some
>   other thread to change the process's access to the memory being
>   tested. Even when the function indicates that the process has read
>   access to the specified memory, you should use structured exception
>   handling when attempting to access the memory. Use of structured
>   exception handling enables the system to notify the process if an
>   access violation exception occurs, giving the process an opportunity
>   to handle the exception.

Other than that, the only chance is asking your memory manager, e.g. through `VirtualQueryEx()`, as suggested by [500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448932/500-internal-server-error) above.

But even this still is not bullet-proof, and I would strongly advise to **solve the real issue instead - whatever that is exactly**. Sure as hell it is not the question, whether the byte at `(($0059724C^ + 76)^` is readable memory in your address space.

Comment: `IsBadReadPtr` should never be depended on, at least in the opinion of [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx)

Comment: Great comment on why not using IsBadPtr: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx

Comment: @mrabat - Are you aware that you have linked the exactly same article as Ken White - only 10 hours later?

Comment: Ha! No not at all. Sorry for that I didn't see the link